# Discord response unauthorized after attempting to send a message through CURL

Tags: php, curl, discord

I've been trying to send a message to my server for a few hours now and failing to do so.
I can receive certain data but i cannot send any message and I'm wondering if i am doing something wrong.

This is my current attempt:

```
<?php

class Discord {

    public static $instance;
    public static $api = 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/';
    public static $auth = 'Authorization: Bot ' . config['bot_token'];

    private static function generateInstance($request_url, $fields) {

        self::$instance = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array(self::$instance, array(
            CURLOPT_URL            => $request_url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => [self::$auth, 'Content-Type: application/json'],
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $fields
        ));
        $response = curl_exec(self::$instance);
        curl_close(self::$instance);

        return $response;

    }

    public static function sendMessage() {

        return self::generateInstance(self::$api . '/channels/' . intval(632172270751711247) . '/messages', [
            'content' => "Hello"
        ]);

    }

}
```

The response being:

```
string(42) "{"message": "Unauthorized", "code": 40001}"
```